# Remote control automation on windows/Ios

Tags: remote-desktop, remoteapp

I am working for an educationnal center and I have some question.
I have 20 iMac, and 50 Windows, all of them with specific software.
Due to the covid, I am looking for a way to remote control to those equipments.
For now, I am using Teamviewer, and it's working well, but it is time consuming because:
There is a group of student from 2pm to 4 pm then another group from 4pm to 6pm.

I change the password for each computer for each session, and send those passwords to the new group.
Do you see a way to automatize this process ? (Maybe with a central management tools) ?

Thanks

Comment: Do you got a licensed version of teamviewer ? If no please find another software.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's a bunch of different ways you could do this. I'm not much for Macs but here's a couple for Windows off the top of my head:

1. You could use Active Directory to join all the machines to a domain and issue passwords to users in AD versus on the computers themselves. This would mean you could set passwords centrally and only need to disable the accounts when the user is no longer enrolled in classes.
2. You could utilize remote commands to set passwords. Powershell for example has a `set-localuser` cmdlet that would allow you to set a password on a machine. This could be done in combination with something like `invoke-command` to remotely set passwords on a bunch of computers.
3. Set up a script that runs on a scheduled task to change passwords at specified times/intervals.